# SplitViewController Portrait PopOver Issue

Tags: iphone, uisplitviewcontroller, ipad

When I switch my iPAD to portrait mode the navigation bar buttons button appears correctly. Now If i choose a table row from popOver View and push a new screen for the master and detail view the navigation bar button disappears and wont appear until I rotate the device to Landscape and then back to Portrait. Does anyone have a idea how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are not setting the delegate in the UISplitViewController

```
self.delegate = secondViewController;
```